# Printing a php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, printing

I am trying to print an array.

First example.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT 
ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute AS attribute_id, 
ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_id AS base_product, 
ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_qty AS qty_base_product, 
ps_stock_available.quantity AS base_product_on_hand, 
FLOOR(ps_stock_available.quantity / ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_qty) AS available_to_customer 
FROM ps_product_attribute 
JOIN ps_advanced_attributes ON ps_advanced_attributes.attribute_id = ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute 
JOIN ps_stock_available ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_id 
ORDER BY ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute ASC, ps_stock_available.quantity DESC");

echo '<pre>';   
WHILE($db_field2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
print_r($db_field2);}
echo  '</pre>';
```

Gives this result...

```
Array(
    [0] => 6703
    [attribute_id] => 6703
    [1] => 382
    [base_product] => 382
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 69
    [base_product_on_hand] => 69
    [4] => 69
    [available_to_customer] => 69
)
```

Only this one result

example 2...

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT 
ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute AS attribute_id, 
ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_id AS base_product, 
ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_qty AS qty_base_product, 
ps_stock_available.quantity AS base_product_on_hand, 
FLOOR(ps_stock_available.quantity / ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_qty) AS available_to_customer 
FROM ps_product_attribute 
JOIN ps_advanced_attributes ON ps_advanced_attributes.attribute_id = ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute 
JOIN ps_stock_available ON ps_stock_available.id_product = ps_advanced_attributes.pack_product_id 
ORDER BY ps_product_attribute.id_product_attribute ASC, ps_stock_available.quantity DESC");

echo '<pre>';   
WHILE($db_field2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
print_r($db_field2);}
echo  '</pre>';
```

Nets this result...

```
Array

(

    [0] => 6703
    [attribute_id] => 6703
    [1] => 382
    [base_product] => 382
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 69
    [base_product_on_hand] => 69
    [4] => 69
    [available_to_customer] => 69
)

Array

(

    [0] => 6703
    [attribute_id] => 6703
    [1] => 103
    [base_product] => 103
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [base_product_on_hand] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [available_to_customer] => 4
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6703
    [attribute_id] => 6703
    [1] => 471
    [base_product] => 471
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [base_product_on_hand] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [available_to_customer] => 0
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6704
    [attribute_id] => 6704
    [1] => 103
    [base_product] => 103
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [base_product_on_hand] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [available_to_customer] => 4
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6704
    [attribute_id] => 6704
    [1] => 397
    [base_product] => 397
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [base_product_on_hand] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [available_to_customer] => 0
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6704
    [attribute_id] => 6704
    [1] => 465
    [base_product] => 465
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [base_product_on_hand] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [available_to_customer] => 0
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6705
    [attribute_id] => 6705
    [1] => 103
    [base_product] => 103
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [base_product_on_hand] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [available_to_customer] => 4
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6705
    [attribute_id] => 6705
    [1] => 533
    [base_product] => 533
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [base_product_on_hand] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [available_to_customer] => 2
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6705
    [attribute_id] => 6705
    [1] => 469
    [base_product] => 469
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [base_product_on_hand] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [available_to_customer] => 0
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6706
    [attribute_id] => 6706
    [1] => 395
    [base_product] => 395
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 41
    [base_product_on_hand] => 41
    [4] => 41
    [available_to_customer] => 41
)
Array
(

    [0] => 6706
    [attribute_id] => 6706
    [1] => 103
    [base_product] => 103
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [base_product_on_hand] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [available_to_customer] => 4
)

Array
(

    [0] => 6706
    [attribute_id] => 6706
    [1] => 468
    [base_product] => 468
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [base_product_on_hand] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [available_to_customer] => 0
)
```

As you can see, lots of results but not quite what I was expecting to see. On both examples I am getting duplicate data.

Am I doing something wrong here? I thought the first example should have printed the entire contents of the array.

Comment: are you saying hte query us wrong or the display? im not clear as to what is at issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first fetch all results to the array, and only then print it

```
$result = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $result[] = $row;
} 
print_r($result);
```

UPD: to get rid of duplicate data use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array

UPD2: consider using mysqli extension instead of mysql. [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the first issue. Any ideas on getting rid of the duplicated data?

Comment: Thanks, that solve the main probem. any ideas on how to get rid of the duplicate dataArray

(

    [0] => 6703
    [attribute_id] => 6703
    [1] => 103
    [base_product] => 103
    [2] => 1
    [qty_base_product] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [base_product_on_hand] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [available_to_customer] => 4
)

Comment: @Coathanger replace mysql_fetch_array with mysql_fetch_assoc